# UITableView Swipe to delete: how to customize button and action?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I want to perform different action, not delete objects but archive them. 
When user swiped on tableViewCell I need to show "Archive" instead of delete. change "Delete" button text and color to something else.

How do I customize "Delete mode" appearance?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Apparently in 3.0 and later there is such method:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_3_0);
```

Comment: Thank you. The fact that this is a thing needs to be publicized more!