# iPhone Dev: Swipe a UITableCell

Tags: iphone

How does one program the ability to swipe a UITableCell. I already have a subclass that I've been working with of UITableCell. Do I just handle swipes in it, like I would a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement this method:

```
tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:
```

and return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete`

To make it work you'll also want to implement these methods:

```
tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:
```

To customize the text of the delete button see this thread:
[UITableView Swipe to delete: how to customize button and action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276871/uitableview-swipe-to-delete-how-to-customize-button-and-action)