# how to create a delete button when user swipe a cell in table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITableViewCell show delete button on swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309484/uitableviewcell-show-delete-button-on-swipe)
>   [iPhone Dev: Swipe a UITableCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259479/iphone-dev-swipe-a-uitablecell)

i want to create delete button when user swipe a cell in table view.If user swipe a cell table goes into edit mode and allows them to delete a swipe cell.

Answer (score 3):

```
 - (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
        {
                    yourTableView.editing = YES;
                    // your code for deletion here
        }


 }
```

Answer (score 2):

U can refer to [this](http://learn-iphone-app-development.com/2011/01/31/tables-part-iii-%E2%80%94-re-ordering-moving-cells-and-swipe-to-delete/).